# Modify an existing xlsx file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

I have an issue with the use of Pandas + ExcelWriter + load_workbook.
My need is to be able to modify data from an existing excel file (without deleting the rest).
It works partly, but when I check the size of the produced file and the original one the size is quite different.
Moreover, it seems to lack some properties. Which leads to an error message when I want to integrate the modified file into an application.
The code bellow :

```
data_filtered = pd.DataFrame([date, date, date, date], index=[2,3,4,5])
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_origin)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_modif, engine='openpyxl',datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss', date_format='dd/mm/yyyy')
writer.book = book
## ExcelWriter for some reason uses writer.sheets to access the sheet.
## If you leave it empty it will not know that sheet Main is already there
## and will create a new sheet.
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
data_filtered.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="PCA pour intégration", index=False, startrow=2, startcol=5, header=False, verbose=True)
writer.save()`
```

Comment: Why are you using openpyxl and Pandas together? Pandas uses openpyxl itself in the `ExcelWriter` class. You should be able to just use `ExcelWriter` as demonstrated in the examples in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Comment: Ok thanks,
I tried it but I have the same issue.
The code bellow : 

data_filtered = pd.DataFrame(
        [date, date, date, date], 
        index=[2,3,4,5]
    )

    with pd.ExcelWriter(
        file_origin,
        engine="openpyxl",
        mode="a",        
        datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss', 
        date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
        if_sheet_exists="overlay",

    ) as writer:
        data_filtered.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="PCA pour intégration", index=False, startrow=2, startcol=5, header=False, verbose=True)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: MIME TYPE ERROR
When I verify this the original file (not modify) I have the MIME TYPE :
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
and when I try with the modify file I have :
"application/octet-stream"